# How split a string separated by comma?

Tags: php

I want to display the string in comma separated by comma

Here is my code

```
function GetItemIds()
{
    $i=0;

    $query="SELECT item_id FROM common.items ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 10";
    $str="";

    $result= mysql_query($query);

    while($result1= mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
         if($i==0)
         {
           $str .= $result1[0];
         }
          else
         {
         $str .=",".$result1[0];
         }
      }

       echo $strs;
     }
```

but here I print str I have output 12345678 like this but I want 1,2,3,4 so please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: it could be also more elegant (but likely it's a matter of taste) to push elements in an array and then use the join/implode function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way:

```
function GetItemIds($num = 10) {
    $q = "SELECT item_id FROM common.items ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT " . $num;
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $ids = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $ids[] = $row['item_id'];
    }
    return implode(',', $ids);
}

echo GetItemIds();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously, you're not increasing the `$i` variable at the end of the loop.

Comment: Obviously? Obviously it wasn't so obvious.

Comment: hm,if you read "abc" when you expect "a,b,c" it must be since it never executes `$str .= ",".$result1[0];` and if it never executes it, it means that $i is never != 0, and the most obvious reason of such an event (before thinking about obscure bugs) is that $i does not change, and $i does not change if you do not change it, so it is missing an update on $i... the *obviously* was not so ridicolous. The fact that such errors bump no at eyes in a small amount of time does not mean that the reason why something happen is not obvious in general. To the OP too, now, it'll look obvious!

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation idea:

```
$a = array();
while($result1= mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $a[] = $result1[0];
    }
echo implode(',', $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks if `$i == 0`, and if it is you do `$str .= $result1[0]`.

After defining `$i` as `0` you never change it. Add `$i++` to the end of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetItemIds()
{
    $i=0;

    $query="SELECT item_id FROM common.items ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 10";
    $str = "";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($result1 = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
       if($i == 0)
       {
           $str .= $result1[0];
       }
       else
       {
           $str .=",".$result1[0];
       }

       $i++;
    }

    echo $strs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array and then join:

```
  $arr = array();
  while( $result1 = mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {
     array_push($arr, $result1[0]);
  }
  return join(",", $arr);
```

About your code you need to increment $i, and return $str not $strs... (typo error only I suppose)

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to make a formatted string from an the result array.

replace

```
while($result1= mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
...
}
```

by

```
mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM);
$str = implode(',',$result);
```